# Firebase not working. Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to register an user but it didn't work. When I check the console.firebase the user has not been created. 
Here is my code:

```
    //registering
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("trying@gmail.com", "justtesting")
          .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  if(task.isSuccessful()){
                      Log.i("test", "success");
                  }
                  else{
                      Log.i("test", "did not work");
                  }
              }
          });
```

[image]

[image: It's in portuguese, but says "actived" in the status]

Comment: Did you enable the email/password sign-in method for your project?

Comment: Yes. I posted a picture now, it's in portuguese but it says "actived" in the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have not added the listeners:

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in
        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
    } else {
        // User is signed out
        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
    }
    // ...
}
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
super.onStop();
if (mAuthListener != null) {
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
}
```

Plesae follow the complete tutorial at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Comment: Hi, I followed and did the same code from the tutorial, everything seems ok. And I also tried to follow a tutorial from youtube, and also does not work. I think that maybe I'm missing something in the gradle, or in the console.firebase

Comment: Share your code, if possible. Also make sure that you are using Firebase SDK 10.x

Comment: By Firebase SDK 10, you mean this: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'   ?

Comment: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1' for Firebase Auth

Comment: I was using the 9x version, thanks for the advice, but I cannot set this one because I got this error when sync the gradle: "Failed to resolve: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'"

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem! I was testing my app in the android studio emulator. That was the issue, I downloaded the APK to my phone and it is working perfectly!

Comment: seriously!! i was stuck on it for hours cuz i was testing on my emulator as well!!