# Android studio firebase Authentication doesn't sign up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a user sign up and login method. However when i sign up it is not showing me any signed up user data in firebase.
Here is my MainActivity.

```
package com.mike.mikeproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private DatabaseReference lDatabase;

private EditText email;
private EditText password;
private Button signup;
private Button login;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    lDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_password);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_btn);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user == null){




            }else {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));


            }


        }
    };





    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            String emailtodb = email.getText().toString().trim();

            String passwordtodb = password.getText().toString().trim();

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign up button clickeddd"+emailtodb+passwordtodb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(emailtodb) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordtodb)){



                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailtodb,passwordtodb).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){


                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,WelcomeActivity.class));



                        } else {


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign up failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"email and password required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }





        }
    });


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));

        }
    });




}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();



    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }


  } 
}
```

What is wrong with my code? why is it not signing up. Thanks in advance.

firebase user record:

[image]

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: no errors bro. like once i press sign up button the sign up process is not happening and in my firebase i cannot see any data(added a screenshot to my question)

Comment: Did you added the 'INTERNET' permission to manifest ?

Comment: yes i did add "INTERNET" Permisission

Comment: I also checked if its the problem with the button, i placed a Toast after sign_up button clicked . it does work. also checked if email and password data is passing from the field. it is also fine. I dont know why this is not signing up. in firebase sign up with email and password is enabled as well

Comment: Try entering correct email format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139949/discussion-between-shashidhar-and-mikethetechy).

Comment: @Shashidar bro!! found the culprit.. it works when i exported as .apk and tested on my phone! - - . luckily found this person saying it worked for him on the phone too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014682/firebase-not-working-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was if you are doing everything right and it doesnt work or signsup the user. it is because it looks like it won't sign up using the emulators. has to be on a real android device..it worked for me using my phone. just export as .apk and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your password greater than 6 characters.